# How to Mine Data from a Facebook Group using R?

Tags: r, facebook, facebook-graph-api, web-analytics

I am using RFacebook package to do data mining.
For example, to get the [facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/facebook) then we do

`fb_page <- getPage(page="facebook", token=fb_oauth)`

In my case is it is a private group and the URL is something like [this](http://facebook.com/group/222568978569). So how do I get the page info for a group? I tried the following but got the following error.

> Error in callAPI(url = url, token = token) :    Unknown path
>   components: /posts

```
  my_page <- getPage(page="group/222568978569", token=my_oauth)
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn´t a reproducible example because the page you mention doesn´t exist.  But I suggest that you check that this group has authorized your app.  Note that after the introduction of version 2.0 of the Graph API, only friends/groups who are using the application that you used to generate the token to query the API will be returned.

Comment: Thank you SCallan. The creator of this group has given me admin right. Could you kindly suggest me how a group member can authorize the app that I used to generate the tocken? It would be very helpfull for me if there is a step by step tutorial/documentation somewhere. Once again thank you for the lead.

Comment: do you mean to use the getGroup function?